# SQL Execute AS userA vs Login as userA

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I have a tableA that disallow userA to update it. (userA is a DB user)

```
DENY UPDATE ON tableA TO userA;
```

When I login with Window Authentication, I update tableA with below query.

[Query]:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'userA';
GO
update tableA set colA='0001' where id=1;
GO 
REVERT;
```

[Message]:

> The UPDATE permission was denied on the object
>   'tableA', database 'DW', schema 'dbo'.

====> This is my expected result.

However, when I changed to login as 'userA' with SQL Server Authentication.

[Query]:

```
update tableA set colA='0001' where id=1
```

====> It allowed to update! It is supposed to block from updating, right? May I know why it does not block it? Anything I have missed out?

Comment: something weird !, how table name is `TableA`, and the error text is mentioned  `udtDW_CFG_SitePlantMaster` as object name !

Comment: is login `userA` same as user `userA` ?

Comment: hi @ahmedabdelqader, sorry is my mistake.

Comment: hi @Squirrel, yes, is same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happen if the *login* `userA` is a member of the `sysadmin` server role.

To get the actual behavior of this login, you should impersonate the login instead of the user:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='userA'
```

When you impersonate the user, only the rights explicitly granted to the user (in the current database) are considered. When you impersonate the login, also the server-level rights are considered.

If a login is a member of the `sysadmin` server role, the permissions (including any explicit DENY) are not verified anymore. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-transact-sql, "DENY does not apply to object owners or members of the sysadmin fixed server role".

Comment: To verify the database user associated with the login, one can test with `EXECUTE AS LOGIN='userA';SELECT USER;REVERT;`. This will return `dbo` in the case of a sysadmin server role member.

Comment: Hi @Razvan, thank you so much for the answer! it is really due to the sysadmin server role. :)